# How to keep separate alignment between the list content and its numbering in html keeping list-style-position to inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have following list and its styling

```
ol {
  background: #ff9999;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ol li {
  background: #ffe5e5;
  padding: 5px;
}

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>
```

I am trying the keep all list numbers to inside in list item so that the numbers should remain left aligned with all number, the problem is that due to this the text is now wrapped and it is aligned with list item number, I want that text should be aligned with itself and not the number.
How to do that ?

Following is the screenshot, as you can see the text is not aligned when it is large in length
[image]

Comment: is like this http://prntscr.com/s0clma  ?

Comment: No the number should be inside, the screenshot you have posted showing the number outside and hence they are not left  aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
ol {
  background: #ff9999;
  counter-reset: foo;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px;
}

ol>li {
  background: #ffe5e5;
  counter-increment: foo;
  display: table-row;
}

ol>li::before {
  content: counter(foo) ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left; /* change this for number alignment right/left. */
  padding-right:5px; /* Increase this for space between number and text.*/
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis facilis mollitia delectus nostrum illum. Ratione a autem, officiis ipsum tempore non ab consectetur illum commodi vitae quas. Beatae sit qui, officia sapiente debitis neque veniam deleniti
    amet officiis minus ipsam doloremque dignissimos aliquid commodi sequi, nulla ullam molestias voluptate natus.</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer and I appreciate you effort, but one this is pending how to keep list numbers left-aligned, how can we do that ?

Comment: It is left aligned if you need other way then change to this: ` text-align: left;` in `ol>li::before {...}`.

Comment: I have changed it to `left` if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS will work fine:

```css
ol {
    border: solid 20px #ff9999;
    background: #ffe5e5;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: count;
}

ol li {
    padding: 5px;
    counter-increment: section;
    display: flex;
}

ol li:before {
    content: counter(section) ".";
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis facilis mollitia delectus nostrum illum. Ratione a autem, officiis ipsum tempore non ab consectetur illum commodi vitae quas. Beatae sit qui, officia sapiente debitis neque veniam deleniti amet officiis minus ipsam doloremque dignissimos aliquid commodi sequi, nulla ullam molestias voluptate natus.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Libero, facere ex voluptatem aspernatur!</li>
    <li>Quis magnam, voluptates error sunt.</li>
    <li>Nesciunt dolor, deleniti repudiandae iusto?</li>
    <li>Dolorem ea alias, sapiente hic!</li>
    <li>Rem sit, error ex? Maxime.</li>
    <li>Itaque commodi odit maxime pariatur.</li>
    <li>Aliquid odio cum vitae animi!</li>
    <li>Ipsa, ex! Ullam, ipsa, laboriosam?</li>
    <li>Culpa nemo illum, deleniti itaque.</li>
    <li>Velit similique incidunt placeat ducimus!</li>
    <li>Sit vel perspiciatis, voluptas itaque.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: But what if number is greater than 10 now the numbers will not be aligned (I mean left align) it is actually be right aligned by default, my requirement that it should be left aligned i.e number 1 and 10 should be left aligned, how can I do that

Comment: You should use the css `counter` for that case. I have updated the snippet.